# How to enable button?

Tags: asp.net

On page load using javascript, I disable the button.

That is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
{
  btnExcel.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " +  
  ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnExcel, null) + ";");     
}
```

Now, I want is to enable the button control

```
protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    1.  Rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel, Response, true, "Project Summary Report");

    2.  btnexcel.enable=true;
}
```

After executing 1 statement on the `btn_click` event,

why 2 statement is not executed?

If 2 statement not executed then my button control not enable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**On page_Load:**

**Code-behind:**

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script1", "disable();", True)
```

**After button Click:**

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script2", "enable();", True)
```

In your head tag:

```
disable(){
 $("#somebtn").attr("disabled", true);
}

enable(){
 $('#somebtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```